# Do I need the Internet-permission tag to provide links in an app?

Tags: android, permissions

Description of the permission:

"Allows applications to open network sockets."

It doesn't seem like I need this permission since it seems like if you try to do something that requires specific permission-tags and you don't have that tag, you'll end up with an error message.
Also, it seems weird that links would somehow enable a disabled internet connection.

I just want to be 100% sure, since this permission can scare people.

And just to clarify:

I have a list of clickable items. When you click one of them, a browser is opened and you are sent to a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sending an intent which is handled by a browser application, your application does not need internet permission.

If you are opening a webview within your own application, then it does.