# Can't get permissions even with included INTERNET permission

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, genymotion, user-permissions

**EDIT:** message about `uses-permission` is not allowed here no longer appears.

I'm using Volley to access google books, api is icecreamsandwich. Even including permissions to the manifest file I still get exception about permissions. I've already read some answered questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705899/android-permission-internet), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)). When pointing to the `uses-permission` by cursor, it says that the tag is not allowed here. How can I solve the problem?

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alone.findgooglebook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Function where I use the `Volley`

```
private void onSearchClicked() {
        String bookName = editText.getText().toString();
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + bookName;

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError err)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        );

        queue.add(request);
    }
```

`editText` is properly initialized by finding the view.

Logcat:

> 06-09 04:43:58.895 9190-9364/com.example.alone.findgooglebook
>   E/Volley: [114] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET
>   permission?)
>                                                                           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET
>   permission?)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
>                                                                            Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No
>   address associated with hostname)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
>                                                                            Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 
>                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
>   06-09 04:43:58.903 9190-9190/com.example.alone.findgooglebook
>   E/MainActivity: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied
>   (missing INTERNET permission?)

Comment: what is your app compileSdkVersion?

Comment: it's icecreamsandwich, can't recall the number. I'll edit the post

Comment: It's `<uses-permission>`, not `<user-permission>`. use**s**, not use**r**.

Comment: @MikeM. Still getting the same error. I will post logcat shortly

Comment: @Mike.M, applied your comment to the post, the logcat is taken after applying it.

Comment: does your app require location ?

Comment: @shuvro, no. It only queries google books by given string by the user

Comment: Can it be due to some sort of firewall? There were no popups about firewall exceptions when I was using the vm nor when I installed it.

Comment: could you also please show your build.gradle to check the SDKs

Comment: @and_dev,     compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' is there

Comment: compile / target / min SDK versions are more relevant

Comment: "When pointing to the `uses-permission` by cursor, it says that the tag is not allowed here." - You changed it to `uses` in that sentence. Does that mean it still says that tag is not allowed there, after the correction?

Comment: @MikeM., no. Thanks, will edit the post

Comment: Then clean and rebuild the project, restart your IDE, reboot the device/emulator, uninstall/reinstall the app, etc. That should be working.

Comment: @MikeM., worked! Thank you. Last question: should I leave the post or delete it, since it's somewhere around typo?

Comment: It's up to you, I guess. I voted to close it as a typo. If you want to delete it, do it quickly, before someone mistakenly upvotes an answer.

Comment: Oh, wait. It's got two answers, now, so I don't think you can delete it. I guess, just wait for 4 more close votes.

Comment: @MikeM. I've flagged it myself, waiting for moderator intervention

Answer (score 0):

I assume your targetSdk is set to 23 so you have to ask the user for permissions. A quickfix would be to set the targetSdk=22 and all should work then.

Comment: Ok so please provide some logcat with the errors you face

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and add your activity name with package like

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Let me  know if it works